# Plot graph of a function with arbitrary constants

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm wondering if is it possible to plot a graph of a function with arbitrary constants.

Here's an example to make things clearer.
If I have a function $$f(x) = \cos(bx) + bx$$
Can I plot this f(x) without giving a specific value for b?

Comment: With Manipulate you can set a range for b and see how it affects the plot.

Comment: Manipulate[Plot[Cos[b x] + b x, {x, 0, 2Pi}], {b, 0, 3}]

Comment: `Can I plot this f(x) without giving a specific value for b?` The short answer is "no". Please lookup `FunctionDomain` and `FunctionRange` as those may help you in certain instances to plot a region of interest.

Comment: Do you want to draw all of the curves for  `-2<=b<=2`?

Comment: If you use free form syntax with Ctrl + = then type plot Cos[x*b]+x*b you will get a 3 D plot if you want that. It might be easier to visualize the curve for different `b` with the suggestion above to use `Manipulate` or the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Different values of $b$ correspond to different scales of the $x$-axis (I will assume $b>0$). Therefore, one could use a plot of this kind:

[image]

**Code:**

```
With[{xs=Range[-3*Pi,3*Pi,Pi]},
 Plot[Cos[x]+x,{x,Min[xs],Max[xs]},
  Ticks->{{xs,xs/"b"}//Transpose,Automatic}]]
```